# How to initialize APDS-9930 ambient light / proximity sensor using ARDUINO Mega2560

Tags: arduino, sensors

I have bought a "APDS-9930" ambient light sensor, which communicates over I2C (TWI) protocol. I intend to read the the ambient light level from it, using ARDUINO Mega2560 development board. As I searched the net, I found a modified ARDUINO library, based on APDS-9960, which claims to work with APDS-9930 on ARDUINO UNO. However, when used with Mega2560, It gives me "Error initializing" error. Does anyone here know how to handle this error?

I have already used "Wire.h" library in many ways, to read "CH0 ADC data register" with address 0x14, which holds the ambient level value (according to datasheet). The code is as follows:

```
#define DUMP_REGS

#include <Wire.h>
#include <APDS9930.h>

// Global Variables
APDS9930 apds = APDS9930();
float ambient_light = 0; // can also be an unsigned long
uint16_t ch0 = 0;
uint16_t ch1 = 1;

void setup() {
  //analogReference(EXTERNAL);

  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("--------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("APDS-9930 - Ambient light sensor"));
  Serial.println(F("--------------------------------"));

  // Initialize APDS-9930 (configure I2C and initial values)
  //if ( apds.init() ) {
   // Serial.println(F("APDS-9930 initialization complete"));
  //} else {
  //  Serial.println(F("Something went wrong during APDS-9930 init!"));
 // }

  // Start running the APDS-9930 light sensor (no interrupts)
  //if ( apds.enableLightSensor(false) ) {
   // Serial.println(F("Light sensor is now running"));
 // } else {
 //   Serial.println(F("Something went wrong during light sensor init!"));
 // }

#ifdef DUMP_REGS
  /* Register dump */
  uint8_t reg;
  uint8_t val;

  for(reg = 0x00; reg <= 0x19; reg++) {
    if( (reg != 0x10) && \
        (reg != 0x11) )
    {
      apds.wireReadDataByte(reg, val);
      Serial.print(reg, HEX);
      Serial.print(": 0x");
      Serial.println(val, HEX);
    }
  }
  apds.wireReadDataByte(0x1E, val);
  Serial.print(0x1E, HEX);
  Serial.print(": 0x");
  Serial.println(val, HEX);
#endif

  // Wait for initialization and calibration to finish
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {

  // Read the light levels (ambient, red, green, blue)
  if (  !apds.readAmbientLightLux(ambient_light) ||
        !apds.readCh0Light(ch0) || 
        !apds.readCh1Light(ch1) ) {
    Serial.println(F("Error reading light values"));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("Ambient: "));
    Serial.print(ambient_light);
    Serial.print(F("  Ch0: "));
    Serial.print(ch0);
    Serial.print(F("  Ch1: "));
    Serial.println(ch1);
  }

  // Wait 1 second before next reading
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: What board pins are you using to connect the sensor?

Comment: I used both sets of SCK and SDA pins on Mega, as well as 3.3V and GND. It's also notable that using an ID_Scanner sketch (which determines the slave ID of the connected I2C modules), I was successful to find its slave ID, which is 0x39. So it seems that the pins are connected correctly.

Comment: I think your board might be 5v logic and the sensor you're trying to use is 3.3v. Have you checked if pins 20 and 21 are connected to +5v through resistors?

Comment: The ARDUINO Mega has both 3.3V and 5V outputs. In this case, I used 3.3V according to the datasheet. However, I didn't quite get your point. Pins 20 an 21 are SDA and SCK respectively. I don't think these pins should be connected to either 3.3V or 5V.

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote was not very clear, I was on mobile. What I meant is that the Mega's I2C bus on pins 20 and 21 is meant to be used with 5V devices because it has two pull-up resistors connecting those lines to +5V. See [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/41562/57433) and [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf). There are two resistors connecting pins SDA and SCK to +5V on the center-top side of the drawing.

Comment: Those resistors should be close to the ON LED. As far as I know, you need a level shifter. Otherwise, you can remove the resistors on the board and place them externally tied to +3.3V instead. See [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=129930.0).

Comment: Thank you very much Marcos. I've been modifying the code for several days, and I didn't know that the problem is actually hardware related. After reading your reply, I searched google for level shifter (since I don't want to desolder the on-board resistors) and I found NXP 2n7000 FET, which seems to be popular for this purpose. I suppose this would solve my problem. Thank you again

Comment: Yes, I guess that should work. You're welcome. I'll write an answer to close the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the issue is hardware related.

On the Arduino Mega 2560 [board](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf) there are two resistances tying lines SDA and SCK (pins 20 and 21 on the connector) to +5V.

With those pull-up resistances, it's not possible to interface with sensors working at 3.3V directly.

The solution is to add a level shifter or remove the resistances on the board and install them externally connecting them to 5V or 3.3V as necessary depending on the sensor you want to interface to.